# big table in appendix

Tags: tables

I'm new to using latex.
and i have a large table of 250 rows and 7 columns
And if you try to write it
more than half the table is not present so that only one page exists
Similar to the picture
[image]

and i want to notate some information under the table
 if  i write something that appears above the table 
i needed  solution

Comment: take a look to `longtable` package and its usage. You have to change your `table` environment  to a `longtable`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Thisis not very clear: the table in your picture has much more than 7 columns, and it's typed in landscape format. Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: sorry the table in the picture is not my original table but the  problem is  the same which is the table is not complete - i used longtable package and it is not work

Comment: @Rasha "not work" is not a very useful problem description. Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You can use longtable in landscape, but not on the first page of a chapterr or section.  OTOH, it you put it into a separate document and use pdfpages or \includegraphics...

Answer (score 1):

for starting point (based on guessing since you not provide anything what you try so far), generic form for long tables (as you can find in packages documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{*{7}{c}}
    \caption{caption on the first page}
    \label{tab:longtable}   \\
    \toprule
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption{caption on the other pages (cont.)}    \\
    \toprule
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize(continue on the next page)}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

document you need to compile at least twice that it obtain final form.

Comment: @Rasha, any news?